Pandas to_csv cannot append to file in Databricks cloud (OSError Errno 95 Operation not supported)
Why I am not able to overwrite a file using below code?
I want file b.csv to be created, then appended every iteration. Although I give mode='a' (append), somehow I may create the file but not append to it.
files = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/lake/RAW/test/billion-row-ingestion-time/table/")
parquet_file_list = [each.path for each in files if each.name!='_delta_log/']

for each in parquet_file_list:
    i=0
    df = spark.read.parquet(each).toPandas()
    df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/raw/billion-row-ingestion-time/b.csv', mode='a')
    print("interation: ", i+1)

OUTPUT
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:261, in CSVFormatter.save(self)
    251 self.writer = csvlib.writer(
    252     handles.handle,
    253     lineterminator=self.line_terminator,
   (...)
    258     quotechar=self.quotechar,
    259 )
--> 261 self._save()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:266, in CSVFormatter._save(self)
    265     self._save_header()
--> 266 self._save_body()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:304, in CSVFormatter._save_body(self)
    303     break
--> 304 self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:315, in CSVFormatter._save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
    314 ix = self.data_index[slicer]._format_native_types(**self._number_format)
--> 315 libwriters.write_csv_rows(
    316     data,
    317     ix,
    318     self.nlevels,
    319     self.cols,
    320     self.writer,
    321 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/writers.pyx:55, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows()

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1964363491723333>, line 4
      2 i=0
      3 df = spark.read.parquet(each).toPandas()
----> 4 df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/raw/billion-row-ingestion-time/b.csv', mode='a')
      5 print("interation: ", i+1)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3551, in NDFrame.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3540 df = self if isinstance(self, ABCDataFrame) else self.to_frame()
   3542 formatter = DataFrameFormatter(
   3543     frame=df,
   3544     header=header,
   (...)
   3548     decimal=decimal,
   3549 )
-> 3551 return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
   3552     path_or_buf,
   3553     line_terminator=line_terminator,
   3554     sep=sep,
   3555     encoding=encoding,
   3556     errors=errors,
   3557     compression=compression,
   3558     quoting=quoting,
   3559     columns=columns,
   3560     index_label=index_label,
   3561     mode=mode,
   3562     chunksize=chunksize,
   3563     quotechar=quotechar,
   3564     date_format=date_format,
   3565     doublequote=doublequote,
   3566     escapechar=escapechar,
   3567     storage_options=storage_options,
   3568 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py:1180, in DataFrameRenderer.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1159     created_buffer = False
   1161 csv_formatter = CSVFormatter(
   1162     path_or_buf=path_or_buf,
   1163     line_terminator=line_terminator,
   (...)
   1178     formatter=self.fmt,
   1179 )
-> 1180 csv_formatter.save()
   1182 if created_buffer:
   1183     assert isinstance(path_or_buf, StringIO)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:241, in CSVFormatter.save(self)
    237 """
    238 Create the writer & save.
    239 """
    240 # apply compression and byte/text conversion
--> 241 with get_handle(
    242     self.filepath_or_buffer,
    243     self.mode,
    244     encoding=self.encoding,
    245     errors=self.errors,
    246     compression=self.compression,
    247     storage_options=self.storage_options,
    248 ) as handles:
    249 
    250     # Note: self.encoding is irrelevant here
    251     self.writer = csvlib.writer(
    252         handles.handle,
    253         lineterminator=self.line_terminator,
   (...)
    258         quotechar=self.quotechar,
    259     )
    261     self._save()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:124, in IOHandles.__exit__(self, *args)
    123 def __exit__(self, *args: Any) -> None:
--> 124     self.close()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:116, in IOHandles.close(self)
    114     self.created_handles.remove(self.handle)
    115 for handle in self.created_handles:
--> 116     handle.close()
    117 self.created_handles = []
    118 self.is_wrapped = False

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported


Replace:
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/raw/billion-row-ingestion-time/b.csv', mode='a')

With:
df.to_csv('/tmp/on/your/disk/b.csv', mode='a')

Then upload after the loop:
dbutils.fs.cp('/tmp/on/your/disk/b.csv',
              '/dbfs/FileStore/raw/billion-row-ingestion-time/b.csv')

The problem is that you are attempting to append data to a file saved on an external storage mount point, which is not supported in Databricks (because the underlying storage that is mounted to DBFS does not support append). Hence the work-around is to run the append locally, then upload the entire file to the Databricks file system once that is completed.
More here:

https://kb.databricks.com/dbfs/errno95-operation-not-supported
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#file-system-utility-dbutilsfs

Essentially the same question:

Write CSV file in append mode on Azure Databricks

